# How to change my wallpaper on Windows 10 locked screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

I want to change my wallpaper on the lock screen, but Windows 10 puts my new wallpaper only after starting and unlocking (when I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>), and at startup it shows me the default wallpaper.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is your computer part of Active Directory (company domain?). If you're not sure you can check it with two commands `echo %HOSTNAME%` and `hostname` in cmd (win+R -> type cmd -> enter). If both are the same, than you're not in domain (well, not for 100%, but it's good enough ;) )

Comment: Have you tried to use an image which is exactly the resolution and aspect ratio of your screen? (for example: 1920 x 1080 pixel)

Comment: @Prog Is your computer joined to a domain? If so, it could be Group Policies reverting those back per your changes where that is enforced and pushed to the workstation from the domain group policy settings. Is this machine domain joined, do you have any domain group policies applying to it causing this to occur? If not, do you have any local group policies set causing the default reversion per your changes?

Comment: It is important to note that the _lock screen_ is not the same as the login prompt you see when no user is logged in. // Did you check the “Show lock screen background picture on the sign-in screen” option? What do you mean by “default wallpaper”? If possible, provide a (low-res) photo.

Comment: @1NN yes, i have, but it didn't work

Comment: Since nothing else works, try to do a [startup repair](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/repair-windows-10)

Comment: Are you using a microsoft account, or do you have office 365 installed? Also, take a look at [this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/1385317/714576)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a picture as the lock screen:

[Change your lock screen background](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-lock-screen-background-afb20cda-c9e2-3be2-e2c5-1a1bfe63047c)

Open `Settings`  > `Personalization` > `Lock screen` and select `Picture`

[image: Change your lock screen background]

Comment: I did exactly that, but at the start there is no wallpaper specified by me

Answer (score 1):

Try these answers:

- [folder ownership issues](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-does-my-lock-screen-image-keep-reverting-back/70b65d49-b14e-4f57-b0e7-fbce384135ee)
- [account sync issues](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/lockscreen-and-background-keep-reverting-back/ea4d1df4-6aa2-4252-af7b-786b35f00d78)

And it is always better to put even your custom wallpapers in the `C:/Windows/Web/Wallpapers` or `Screen` folders

[image: Folders to put in]

let me know if it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. moreover, I could not complete any of these decisions, because. I lacked access rights (although I am an administrator and there is one account on my PC)

Comment: copying your pictures into `C:/Windows/Web/Screen` also doesn't work? You can't copy them or the picture reverts back?

Comment: I was able to move the picture to the folder, but the picture reverts back

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the profile created when Windows was first installed (or for some other reason unknown to me), it's possible that you are seeing a generic lock screen image.

There's a [tutorial with explanation on winaero.com](https://winaero.com/how-to-change-default-lock-screen-image-in-windows-10/) on how to resolve this. In synthesis, the steps are:

1. Open the registry, and go to the variable

   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization`
2. Create a new string value named `LockScreenImage`.
3. Set its value data to the full path of the desired image which will be used as the lock screen image.
4. Restart your system.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't work